# Is there a way to import a component library created in react into another project without having to publish it in the npm registry?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've created a component's library in react and built it using rollup, how can I use this components created into another reactjs project without having to publish the library in the npm registry? Is there a way to do it? I've been searching all the week but could not come up with a solution.

I tried to use npm link but it's not working, actually I would like to be able to import the components directly just using one single command.

Comment: Have you checked out Module Federation?

Comment: Gonna take a look and see if that helps, thanks